# Red border doesn't disappear with INotifyDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, .net, validation, xaml

I'm trying to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo but don't have success when I try to validate ObservableCollection properties.

The problem is, I get the red border, if the collection is wrong, but if I correct the collection, the red border doesn't go away anymore.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this?

I setup a small sample to demonstrate the problem:

```
<Window x:Class="Validation.ValidationWindow3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ValidationWindow3" Height="300" Width="300">
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Top">Click button Add two times.<LineBreak/>
        => Red border should appear.<LineBreak/>
        <LineBreak/>
        Select second line in listbox then click button Remove.<LineBreak/>
        =>Red border should disappear.</TextBlock>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Click="OnOk">Ok</Button>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="OnAdd">Add</Button>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="OnRemove">Remove</Button>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfNumbers, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNumber}" />
</DockPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Validation
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for ValidationWindow2.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ValidationWindow3 : Window, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> ListOfNumbers
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<int>)GetValue(ListOfNumbersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ListOfNumbersProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListOfNumbersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ListOfNumbers", typeof(ObservableCollection<int>), typeof(ValidationWindow3), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnPropertyChanged));



    public int SelectedNumber
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SelectedNumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedNumberProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedNumberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedNumber", typeof(int), typeof(ValidationWindow3), new PropertyMetadata(-1));



    public ValidationWindow3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListOfNumbers = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ValidationWindow3 instance = d as ValidationWindow3;
        ObservableCollection<int> coll = (ObservableCollection<int>)e.NewValue;
        coll.CollectionChanged += instance.coll_CollectionChanged;
    }

    void coll_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckProperty("ListOfNumbers");
    }



    private void OnOk(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(HasErrors)
        {
            IEnumerable list = GetErrors(null);
            string msg = "";
            foreach(var item in list)
            {
                msg += item.ToString();
            }
            MessageBox.Show(msg);
            return;
        }
        DialogResult = true;
    }


    void CheckProperty([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        bool isValid = true;
        string msg = null;

        switch(propertyName)
        {
        case "ListOfNumbers":
            msg = "Only even numbers allowed!";
            foreach(int item in ListOfNumbers)
            {
                if(item % 2 > 0)
                {
                    isValid = false;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        if(!isValid)
        {
            AddError(propertyName, msg);
        }
        else if(msg != null)
        {
            RemoveError(propertyName, msg);
        }
    }

    // Adds the specified error to the errors collection if it is not 
    // already present, inserting it in the first position if isWarning is 
    // false. Raises the ErrorsChanged event if the collection changes. 
    public void AddError(string propertyName, string error, bool isWarning=false)
    {
        if(!errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            errors[propertyName] = new List<string>();

        if(!errors[propertyName].Contains(error))
        {
            if(isWarning)
                errors[propertyName].Add(error);
            else
                errors[propertyName].Insert(0, error);
            RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }

    // Removes the specified error from the errors collection if it is
    // present. Raises the ErrorsChanged event if the collection changes.
    public void RemoveError(string propertyName, string error)
    {
        if(errors.ContainsKey(propertyName) &&
            errors[propertyName].Contains(error))
        {
            errors[propertyName].Remove(error);
            if(errors[propertyName].Count == 0)
                errors.Remove(propertyName);
            RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public void RaiseErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(ErrorsChanged != null)
            ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }




    #region INotifyDataErrorInfo Members

    private Dictionary<String, List<String>> errors =
        new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        if (errors.Count < 1)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
        {
            return errors.SelectMany(err => err.Value.ToList());
        }
        if(!errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            return null;
        return errors[propertyName];
    }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get { return errors.Count > 0; }
    }

    #endregion

    static int _nextNumber = 0;

    private void OnAdd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListOfNumbers.Add(_nextNumber++);
    }

    private void OnRemove(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListOfNumbers.Remove(SelectedNumber);
    }
}
}
```

EDIT:

I found out that there is nothing wrong with the validation itself. It seems to be a problem related to the ListBox. If I bind an additional TextBox to the ListOfNumbers I can see that the border on this TextBox works correct.

This is what I added:

```
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding ListOfNumbers, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
```

So why is the red border on the ListBox wrong?

Comment: try [ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validatesonnotifydataerrors(v=vs.110).aspx)="True"

Comment: Doesn't help either.

Comment: Could it be that it's simply a problem in default ErrorTemplate? I verified that on CollectionChanged the collection is validated, ErrorsChanged is raised with "ListOfNumbers" and HasErrors gets called and returns false. So the framework should know that there is no error.

Comment: I am testing your example and could see that the red border goes away when you select the remaining object. It something like the HasErrors is not being raised until the selectednumber changes. You can force a workaround doing something like "SelectedNumber = ListOfNumbers.FirstOrDefault().

Comment: I think this is a bug with the Items Control in WPF, not working well with the new `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface, try the old `IDataErrorInfo`.

Comment: @blacai: I put "if(ListOfNumbers.Count > 0) {SelectedNumber =ListOfNumbers.First(); } else { SelectedNumber = -1; }" in the CollectionChanged handler. This works better, but there is a problem when I remove the last item. There is always the red border, after reomving the last item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the cause:

The ListBox is validating the SelectedItem. So if I delete this item the variable SelectedNumber, which is bound to SelectedItem, has a value that is not in the collection anymore. This gives me the red box.

I don't think that this is correct behaviour of the ListBox, but if I keep this in mind, there are some workarounds that I can use dependent on the situation:

1. After removing the SelectedItem, set the SelectedItem to a different item in the collection, or to -1.
2. Use SelectedIndex instead of SelectedItem, because this doesn't have such problem.
3. Use Mode=OneWay for the SelectedItem binding

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I solved it with removing the Validation.ErrorTemplate like this:

```
<Style>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And add error indication in the DataTemplate of the binded element, like this:

```
 <TextBlock Text="!" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Red" Margin="5" Visibility="{Binding HasErrors, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```